# AngularJS: navigation bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigation

I am trying to implement this example: https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/demo/navBar

So I created following `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="navBardemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
        <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
            <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">Page One</md-nav-item>
            <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page2')" name="page2">Page Two</md-nav-item>
            <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page3')" name="page3">Page Three</md-nav-item>
        </md-nav-bar>
        <div class="ext-content">
            External content for `<span>{{currentNavItem}}</span>`
        </div>
    </md-content></div>

    <script src="vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="app.js"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

and following `app.js`:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
        .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

    function AppCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';
    }
})();
```

I am getting this exception:

```
Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:40:222
    at q (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:39:488
    at q (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at cb (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:43:336)
    at c (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:20:390)
    at Bc (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:21:179
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the reference for the `angular-material.js` and css

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/SgNNqD?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for answer! unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ it should, make sure you load the css as well. here is a demo https://plnkr.co/edit/ok14o9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your ng-app in this example in the body tag just like

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
```

As the documentation points out, you should not put your app and other directives in the same tag

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer! unfortunately it doesn't help